# Why sqoop is throwing error while import?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have just installed sqoop and trying to import table from mysql but it is throwing below error. I am new to sqoop.

```
command -> sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --username root --password Passw0rd --m 1 --table employee --target-dir /home/sayyad/Downloads/sqoop_data

2021-04-20 01:19:43,041 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2021-04-20 01:19:43,204 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.initOptionDefaults(MySQLManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.<init>(SqlManager.java:89)
    
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:38)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:31)
    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have [commons-lang-2.6.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonslang26jar.htm) in lib directory on sqoop home

then you can use `sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --username root -P` command test.